# Cocos2d gameClock update function not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, counter

gameClock is defined the header file

```
@interface UserInputLayer : CCLayer
{
    ccTime gameClock;
}
```

In the init method of the layer I have:

```
[self schedule:@selector(updateClock:)];
```

updateClock looks like this:

```
-(void)updateClock:(ccTime)delta {
    gameClock += delta;
 }
```

but I am getting the error:

```
Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? 
-(void) name: (ccTime) dt
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not used Cocos2D, I would bet that this is because `updateClock:` is not declared in your header, like this:

```
@interface UserInputLayer : CCLayer
{
    ccTime gameClock;
}

-(void)updateClock:(ccTime)delta;

@end
```

Comment: I had tried that also, actually.  I ended up cloning my own git repo and trying again and it worked fine.  Just one of those things, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use [self scheduleUpdate] instead.